# linear integer optimization in pulp

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, glpk, pulp

I was trying to do the following simple example optimization problem before starting a bigger problem. The code:

```
from pulp import *
x = LpVariable("x", 0, 3)
y = LpVariable("y", 0, 1)
prob = LpProblem("myProblem", LpMinimize)

prob += x + y <= 2
#objective function
prob += -4*x + y

status = prob.solve(GLPK(msg = 0))
#results
value(x)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mahabubalam\Desktop\Works\GUI\whiskas.py", line 85, in <module>
    status = prob.solve(GLPK(msg = 0))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.6-py3.4.egg\pulp\pulp.py", line 1619, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pulp-1.5.6-py3.4.egg\pulp\solvers.py", line 335, in actualSolve
    raise PulpSolverError("PuLP: cannot execute "+self.path)
pulp.solvers.PulpSolverError: PuLP: cannot execute glpsol.exe
```

Can anyone please help me to understand why is that?

Comment: Have you tried executing with admin rights?

Comment: I am sorry, I am new in optimization. What did you mean by 'admin rights'? how can I do that?

Comment: Windows admin rights, nothing to do with optimization :). Right click the python file and click "Run as administrator"

Comment: I saved the python file as "whisk.py". I right clicked on the whisk.py file but there is nothing like "Run as administrator". I probably missed something.

Comment: How are you running the programin the first place?

Comment: Have you installed the GLPK?

Comment: I installed pulp. GLPK supposed to comes with pulp, right?

Comment: run pulp.pulpTestAll()

Comment: I did and found the unavailable list:

* Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.PULP_CBC_CMD'> passed.
Solver <class 'pulp.solvers.GLPK_CMD'> unavailable

Comment: So maybe this is what you need: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/

Answer (score 4):

I have successfully run your code after doing the following two steps:

1. Download GLPK from

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/files/latest/download (as mentioned by oyvind)
2. Unzip it into (for example) :
   `C:\glpk_is_here\`
3. Add GLPK binaries to your system path before running python
   `C:\>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\glpk_is_here\glpk-4.55\w64`
4. **Using the same cmd window from (3)**, use python/ipython to run your code:
   `C:\>ipython your_code.py`
5. See the results
   `Out[4]: 2.0`

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I used illegal characters in the name of the variables.  From what I can gather in pulp's code (LpElement, to be exact), the characters `-+[] ->/` are not allowed and are all replaced by an underscore.

Since discovering the error, I preprocess my variable names with the following function, fixing the issue:

```
  def variableName(s):
    # illegalChars = "-+[] ->/"
    s = s.replace("-","(hyphen)")
    s = s.replace("+","(plus)")
    s = s.replace("[","(leftBracket)")
    s = s.replace("]","(rightBracket)")
    s = s.replace(" ","(space)")
    s = s.replace(">","(greaterThan)")
    s = s.replace("/","(slash)")
    return s
```

Comment: This error can also be caused by duplicate LpVariable names.  In my case, I had several different names which were unique before the underscore replacement.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in unbuntu:

```
   sudo apt-get install python-glpk  
   sudo apt-get install glpk-utils
```

I think in windows there is a similar solution

Answer (score 1):

Install GLPK, e.g. from sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk

Answer (score 1):

For Mac -- `brew install glpk` on terminal.

[Homebrew](http://brew.sh) is the best.